# CSF: Changing portflood settings to deny IP longer than second interval?

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, firewall, csf

I've recently been under attack and I'm configuring CSF firewall for my Ubuntu server (latest). I found out portflood settings only block the ip for the specified second count, but I would like separate times. I was thinking forever, but even an hour would do. Is this possible to make it so the "interval seconds" and the amount of time the spammer is blocked are different? if not, is there a different firewall similar to csf that allows this?